# How do I get replacement of only specific text within a line in files?

Tags: powershell, replace

I'm trying to replace an email address string in multiple files to a new value, but I keep getting ONLY the new email address on the line, without what comes before and after the replacement string.
Any ideas?

```
Param(
    [string]$path = ".\Downloads\Backups",
    [string]$filespec = "*.config",
    [regex]$regex = '^(.*)(\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}\b)(.*)$'
)    

[string]$replacement = "${1}newemail@mycompany.com${3}"

Get-ChildItem $path -Include $filespec -Recurse |
    ForEach {
        if (Get-Content $_.FullName | Select-String -Pattern $regex) {
            (Get-Content $_ | ForEach {$_ -replace $regex, $replacement}) |
                Set-Content $_ 
        }
    }
```

The initial file looks like this:

```
add key="EmailSubject" value="Urgent: Original Document FTP Process Errors on server"
add key="Email Address" value="myaddress@mycompany.com"
add key="SenderAddress" value="mail.mycompany.com"
```

The output looks like this:

```
add key="EmailSubject" value="Urgent: Original Document FTP Process Errors on server"
newemail@mycompany.com
add key="SenderAddress" value="mail.mycompany.com"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the example provided, your regex matches the entire string, and thus replaces the entire string.

Change this (https://regex101.com/r/Z84zDL/1)

`[regex]$regex = '^(.*)(\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}\b)(.*)$'`

to this (https://regex101.com/r/vg4LIz/3)

`[regex]$regex = '[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}\b(.*)$'`

Comment: That worked... Except I now don't need the ending group.. But thanks!